# ComboBoxTableCell dependent on another of its kind for JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I wish I could find this myself (found many other helpful answers - from James_D) but here is my story.

1) I have a "central" repository of **Items** that consists of Objects with parameters like below:

```
listOfItems.add(new Item("ABCD", "typeA", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("10", "20", "30")))); 
listOfItems.add(new Item("EFGH", "typeB", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("40", "50", "60"))));
```

2) I have a JavaFx's tableView where I want to store - as rows - some **Components** that consist of 10 values where part of those components are three columns/values from Items repository mentioned @ point number 1.
That made me create "generateCellValueFactory" which looks like this:

```
private void generateCellValueFactory(TableColumn<Component, String> column, String name) {
    if(name.equals("Items_string_one")) {
        column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getProperty(name));
        ArrayList<String> list = itemsRepository.getFirstStrings(); //["ABCD" & "EFGH"]
        generateCombo(column, name,  list);
    } else if (name.equals("Items_lists_of_Strings")) {
        column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getProperty(name));
        List<String> list = itemsRepository.getUniqueStringsListsOfStrings();
// ! Unfortunately -> this returns me UNIQUE like list of every string inside those so in our case: ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60"]
        generateCombo(column, name, list);
// 8 other columns factories - second string from Item + 7 not a part of "Items" repository. Overall 10 columns.
```

3) As we can see we have included internal generateCombo method -> since I want to have ALL ten cells for every Component to be "ComboBoxTableCells" and that one is responsible for setCellFactory part:

```
private void generateCombo(TableColumn<Component, String> column, String name, List<String> list) {
    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
    if (name.equals("Items_string_one")) {
        column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Component, String>, TableCell<Component, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Component, String> call(TableColumn<Component, String> param) {
                ComboBoxTableCell<Component, String> tableCell = new ComboBoxTableCell<Component, String>(data) {
                    @Override
                    public void commitEdit(String x) {
                        // Do something fancy
                     }
                 };
                 return tableCell;
            }
        });
    }else if (name.equals("Items_lists_of_strings")) {
        column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Component, String>, TableCell<Component, String>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Component, String> call(TableColumn<Component, String> param) {
                ComboBoxTableCell<Component, String> tableCell = new ComboBoxTableCell<Component, String>(data) {
                    @Override
                    public void commitEdit(String x) {
                        // Do something fancy
                    }
                };
                return tableCell;
            }
        });
    }
```

Here goes my problem:
Right now when I choose first column I have in comboBox options:
x ABCD     /    EFGH      and this is perfect -> I am glad here.
I am also glad because all oher eight columns are working for me like a charm.

For the "Items_lists_of_Strings" column I can choose from unique list of every possibility. Not bad but also not what I really wanted since I want to have computation "specification_errors-proof" hence when someones chooses ABCD -> he can get 10/20/30 in the other column.
I want to have in this ComboBoxTableCell options "binded" to Items repository that:

IF -> first column -> ABCD
THEN -> ComboBoxTableCell has options "to check" : "10", "20", "30".

I hope I could provide every single detail. I tried to make code for this problem generic.
Thank you in advance and I will await any furter questions and concerns.

Comment: Ugh. I probably found something similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665322/change-itemlist-in-a-combobox-depending-from-another-combobox-choice

Comment: OK. THIS ONE IS CLOSED. The answer (way to do it properly) is in a link above.